# "Unknown problem while loading the specified device driver." error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-playsound

I am making a simple program for my entertainment using the *playsound* module. Here's my code:

```
from playsound import playsound

print("please wait")
playsound("scan.wav")
```

and the error messsage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programi\python\lab\lab.py", line 9, in <module>
    playsound("scan.wav")
  File "C:\Users\ONT Studios\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Users\ONT Studios\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\playsound.py", line 31, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 266 for command:
        open "scan.wav" alias playsound_0.98994089730741
    Unknown problem while loading the specified device driver.
```

This is my path: `D:\Programi\python\lab` with files: `lab.py`, `scan.mp3`, and `scan.wav`.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179727/how-to-fix-unable-to-load-sound-error-with-python-playsound-module), but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue today and I was able to fix it in one way. It is probably a bug but you can get around it. So basically when importing several modules in a row, this will create the error. What I did is import first the playsound module then play one sound and print a bunch of random stuff then import the rest of the modules. This fixed my issue.

```
import mouse
from playsound import playsound

playsound('D:/rakkiz.mp3')
print("\n")
print("\n")
print("\n")
print("\n")

import re
import pywinauto
import time
import keyboard
```

Comment: If you're not importing any other modules and still have this issue, then I'm afraid the solution proposed is not compatible with your case.